# How to prevent web page from downloading same image over and over again?

Tags: html, browser, browser-cache

In my web page I have the same image used ~5000 times in different places.

I always heard that browser will automatically cache images and I should not worry about it, yet, when I profiled my page load in Chrome, it does not seem to be the case. Please find attached screenshot of profiling result:

[image: Page profiling in Chrome]

All the marked red areas is downloading the same image over and over again. It is marked as "Receive Data", so I assume it is indeed downloading it every time.

When I check Resource URL being downloaded, each instance has additional unique id added, like: "https://localhost:44344/images/MenuNode.png?1588089781084", which is not present in my code.

All those downloads are adding up to a noticeable chunk of time.
Is there a way to only download this image once, to speed up overall page load time?

Comment: Well something is adding that url parameter to bust cache. Are you using some sort of framework/build?

Comment: Yes, I am using Blazor (and actually regretting it a little..)

Comment: But now that i think about it, those images are actually "downloaded" with jQuery, by prepending img tag to some elements

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it, for some reason a library I was using to draw charts was detecting all images inside it's nodes html and adding unique identifier to them...